# Add a space in doctrine colum alias via querybuilder

Tags: sql, doctrine, alias

I am trying to add a space in my alias for a column. I already tried the following

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('o').....

o.adress as "Rechnungsadresse (privat)"

o.adress as "Rechnungsadresse \(privat\)"

o.adress as Rechnungsadresse (privat)
```

Is there anyways to escape the space and the brackets? Or do I have to write it in plain SQL?

Comment: Why using such complicated alias? if you want a friendly name for display purpose, do it in the application. (and when you'll translate your application in english, your alias will still be in german?)

Comment: I am encoding the output to CSV format and set an option to download it or send it via mail. I do not need a view for that (it is for admins only)